# Fundamental group of a countable product of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} S^1$ with the product topology. What does the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ look like?

I don't think the countable product of the universal covering map $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is a covering map in this case since any neighborhood of $X$ contains full copies of $S^1$. How can we find the fundamental group without this?

Answer (score 3):

Covering theory is probably not a good approach here, since your space isn't semi-locally simply connected. But it's still true that the fundamental group of a product space is the direct product of the fundamental groups of the factors.  That's because paths, loops, and homotopies in a product spaces are determined by paths, loops, and homotopies in all the factor spaces. So the fundamental group of $(S^1)^{\aleph_0}$ is $\mathbb Z^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Makes sense. So am I right in interpreting this as there's a correspondence between sequences of integers and path homotopy classes $[f] \in \pi_1(X)$ defined by the property that loops in $[f]$ wrap around the $n$th circle $a_n$ times?

Comment: Yes. (I assume "wrap around the $n$th circle $a_n$ times" means that the projection of $f$ to the $n$th circle is in the homotopy class corresponding to $a_n$ in the fundamental group of that circle.)